# PHP Powerpoint and Charts

Tags: php, charts, powerpoint

I am trying to create PowerPoint Presentations via PHP using this [library](http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/). When I try to create Chart objects inside the PowerPoint, I am not able to edit the charts when I download the file and open them in Microsoft Office.

Is there any library which can build charts inside a PowerPoint file and allow it to be edited via Office PowerPoint?

[Sample Chart created using the above library](http://play.mink7.com/h/linechart.pptx)

Comment: "I am not able to edit the charts when I download the file" - version problems maybe? What version does that library create for, and what version of Powerpoint are you running?

Comment: 2007 Powerpoint. i am running 2010 @halfer

Answer (score 6):

This is likely to be a bug with PHP Power Point.

However, the latest version of [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) supports Charting and is actively maintained. It allows you to chart and export your data in excel which can be easily copied to PowerPoint.

*On a personal note though,* I would suggest you use [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples) or [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/analytics.html).

[image: Example chart]

If you want to be able to use the Chart in PowerPoint, you can easily export [Google Charts Data](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples_96cadd85bbec1811fbc395a96a7171e4.frame) to Excel (CSV). Also see [this example](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/excel_google_chart_api/index.htm).

If you are presenting Google Analytics specifically, you should read [this document](http://blog.oomfo.com/2011/10/presenting-real-time-google-analytics-data-in-powerpoint-live-charts-lesser-heartburn-greater-accuracy/) on how to create an accurate automatically updated Chart and Data in PowerPoint from Google Analytics. It basically uses the [oomfo plugin](http://oomfo.com/) for PowerPoint.

Alternatively, there are paid solutions like [ShufflePoint](http://www.shufflepoint.com/PowerPoint.aspx) for this.

Comment: Basically what we are generating is a Reports in the PPT with charts based on analytics. So when users using our service opt to get Charts they should be able to edit it. Using Google chart Tools can i edit it inside PPT ? i dont think so. I will look at Google charts Data

Comment: No, but you can easily export it to excel and then to PowerPoint. However if you are using Google Analytics, there're actually many tools for that... I will update the answer with the links...

Comment: you mean export from PHPExcel and import it into PHP Powerpoint ?

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can export editable charts using PHPPowerPoint. In the tests there are two examples. The first example does not include Excel sheets and that's why the charts are uneditable. But if you look at the second example I think test8 then you will see there is a reference call to PHPExcel and a flag to include the data sheet along with the chart and then you can edit the data.

Answer (score 2):

See this url:-

PHP PowerPoint 2007 classes

Project providing a set of classes for the PHP programming language, which allow you to write to and read from different file formats, like PowerPoint 2007, ... This project is built around Microsoft's OpenXML standard and PHP.

http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/

http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/list/changesets?ProjectName=phppowerpoint

Features

http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Features&referringTitle=Home

try this:-

```
<?php
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/Classes/');

/** PHPPowerPoint */
include 'Classes/PHPPowerPoint.php';

// Create new PHPPowerPoint object
$objPHPPowerPoint = new PHPPowerPoint();
$objPHPPowerPoint->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")->
    setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")->setTitle("Office 2007 PPTX Test Document")->
    setSubject("Office 2007 PPTX Test Document")->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 PPTX, generated using PHP classes.")->
    setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")->setCategory("Test result file");

// Remove first slide
$objPHPPowerPoint->removeSlideByIndex(0);

// Create templated slide

// Create templated slide
$currentSlide = createTemplatedSlide($objPHPPowerPoint);

// Generate sample data for line chart
$seriesData = array('Jul 17' => 15, 'Jul 18' => 27, 'Jul 19' => 17, 'Jul 20' =>
    11, 'Jul 21' => 7, 'Jul 22' => 2, 'Jul 23' => 8);

// Create a line chart (that should be inserted in a shape)
$lineChart = new PHPPowerPoint_Shape_Chart_Type_Scatter();
$series = new PHPPowerPoint_Shape_Chart_Series('Visits', $seriesData);
//$series->setShowSeriesName(true);
$lineChart->addSeries($series);

// Create a shape (chart)
$shape = $currentSlide->createChartShape();
$shape->setName('# of people visiting your website')->setResizeProportional(false)->setHeight(550)->
    setWidth(700)->setOffsetX(120)->setOffsetY(80);
$shape->getShadow()->setVisible(true)->setDirection(45)->setDistance(10);
$shape->getFill()->setFillType(PHPPowerPoint_Style_Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR)->
    setStartColor(new PHPPowerPoint_Style_Color('FFCCCCCC'))->setEndColor(new
    PHPPowerPoint_Style_Color('FFFFFFFF'))->setRotation(270);
$shape->getBorder()->setLineStyle(PHPPowerPoint_Style_Border::LINE_SINGLE);
$shape->getTitle()->setText('# of people visiting your website');
$shape->getTitle()->getFont()->setItalic(true);
$shape->getPlotArea()->setType($lineChart);
$shape->getView3D()->setRotationX(30);
$shape->getView3D()->setPerspective(30);
$shape->getLegend()->getBorder()->setLineStyle(PHPPowerPoint_Style_Border::
    LINE_SINGLE);
$shape->getLegend()->getFont()->setItalic(true);

// Save PowerPoint 2007 file
$objWriter = PHPPowerPoint_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPPowerPoint,
    'PowerPoint2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.pptx', __file__));

function createTemplatedSlide(PHPPowerPoint $objPHPPowerPoint) {
    // Create slide
    $slide = $objPHPPowerPoint->createSlide();

    // Return slide
    return $slide;
}
```

Comment: i am using the same library. I am not able to edit the Charts Data Set once the ppt is generated.

Comment: I have send new code please try this i have include creating a chart:-   // Generate sample data for line chart
$seriesData = array('Jul 17' => 15, 'Jul 18' => 27, 'Jul 19' => 17, 'Jul 20' =>
    11, 'Jul 21' => 7, 'Jul 22' => 2, 'Jul 23' => 8);

// Create a line chart (that should be inserted in a shape)
$lineChart = new PHPPowerPoint_Shape_Chart_Type_Scatter();
$series = new PHPPowerPoint_Shape_Chart_Series('Visits', $seriesData);
//$series->setShowSeriesName(true);
$lineChart->addSeries($series);

// Create a shape (chart)
$shape = $currentSlide->createChartShape();

Comment: should i use the code in the comment ?

Comment: I have added code in my answer take a look my answer

Comment: code is very large so i can't use in comment. that the reason i have added code in answer. I think this code is very help full to you.Please let me now if it is working.

Comment: hey Abid i got the answer. we have to use PHP Excel lib also and just use $shape->setIncludeSpreadsheet(true); to embed the excel into the ppt so that it is editable

Answer (score 0):

The correct example is now called:

`Sample_05_Chart_with_PHPExcel.php`

in the samples folder inside the main PHPPowerpoint (now they are starting to call it PHPPresentation) folder

Note that to make it work you have to change/add a few things.

1. download from GitHub and save somewhere the folder `Common` from PHPOffice
2. include and register the Autoloader from `Common`
3. download from GitHub and save somewhere the `PHPExcel` folder
4. include the main `PHPExcel.php` file
5. In the `Sample_Header.php` file I changed the line

   `Autoloader::register();`

   to

   `PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Autoloader::register();`

   to avoid conflicts (what Autoloader are we registering?)
6. In the `Sample_Header.php` file I also removed (commented) the line:

   `//require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`

   that gave me errors (I am not using composer and don't want composer).

That's all, now it creates a Powerpoint presentation with editable Excel data inside.

This is final code in modified Sample_Header.php (lines 26-28):

```
PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Autoloader::register();

//require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

This is final code added in  modified Sample_05_Chart_with_PHPExcel.php (line 5, after `include_once 'Sample_Header.php';`):

```
require_once '<path to phpExcel...>/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
include '<path to Common...>/Common/Autoloader.php';
PhpOffice\Common\Autoloader::register();
```

Change `<path to phpExcel...>` and `<path to Common...>` with your correct paths.